# Can I use "Divinity of Pride" in my mono black commander deck? If not, then what card is/similar to Divinity of Pride but is a mono black?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I use the MTG card [Divinity of Pride](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDivinity%20of%20Pride%5d) in my mono black commander deck?
It's a multi-colored card - black/white - but it pays for either four swamps (black mana) or four plains (white mana). I know of the rule in commander indicating that "All cards must be in the color identity of the commander." But since this is a black/white and can pay for either four black or four white, I just want to clarify.
So, my question is Can I use Divinity of Pride in a mono black commander deck?
If not, then what card is/similar to Divinity of Pride but is a mono black?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use Divinity of Pride in a mono black commander deck?

No.

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

White appears in Divinity of Pride's mana cost, so it can't be used in your mono-black Commander deck.

---

> If not, then what card is/similar to Divinity of Pride but is a mono black?

There is no [mono-black creature gaining abilities depending on having X "or more life"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22or%20more%20life%22%5D)  – that's an ability associated with white.